# How to download many images with AFNetworking?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, afnetworking, sdwebimage

I am making an app..

I need to download many pictures from a server, but I don't know how to do :(

I try to use this code:

```
UIImageView *image=(UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
NSData * data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"FileName"]];
        if ( data == nil )
            return;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            image.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

        });
        data=nil;
    });
```

This code is slow... I need to do it more quickly... I think AFNetworking is the best option, isn't it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have several options, one of the AFNetworking. However, if you go with AFNetworking, you should use the [UIImageView+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/UIKit+AFNetworking/UIImageView+AFNetworking.h) class, inside the [UIKit+AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/master/UIKit+AFNetworking) folder.

Here's the documentation for it: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.0.1/Categories/UIImageView+AFNetworking.html

Another great option is [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) which gives you more advanced control over caching and image handling, such as processing images before they're displayed, handling your own caching, etc.

Comment: This looks very cool. However I don't see anything in AFNetworking's documentation that allows for more than one image request. It looks like a new request candles the current request. According tot he documents.

Comment: @Tander Yes, if you're using the same `UIImageView`, but you can download as many images as you want at once if you have several `UIImageView`s

Comment: You should know that SDWebImage uses NSURLConnection till the current version. They haven't upgraded to NSURLSession. I would suggest you to use AFNetworking.

Answer (score 1):

AFNetworking would be perfect for your needs. It has its own `UIImageView` category that handles asynchronous image loading very smoothly. Give it a try.

Comment: ok... but this is my problem..i don't know how to use AFNetworking

Comment: Why ? He is saying that his code is slow, how use AFNetworking will speed up his code ?

Comment: He would replace his code with AFNetworking's code. The AFNetworking code is fantastic. - And if you don't know how to use AFNetworking, this is not the place to ask. You seem to lack the fundamental skills required for coding in iOS, and you'd be better off doing a course (such as those provided for free on iTunes U) or learning from a book.

Comment: I know AFNetworking is a fantastic Framework, i'm not asking how to use it. I just asking how AFNetworking will **speed up** his code?

Comment: Because it won't make mistakes like calling `[UIImage imageWithData:]` on the main thread. He's obviously an inexperienced coder while the genius who created AFNetworking knows how to optimise his code.

Comment: Also, I was unclear before - I wasn't referring to you not knowing how to use AFNetworking, I was referring to the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

Like previous answers have suggested, [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) is a great way to go.

I too, though, want to suggest using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). There are a lot of nice features in there, such as cool cache handling and image decompression.

For starters, try doing something like

```
[self.image setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imagePath]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                   [image setImage:image];
}];
```

When it comes to speeding up the code, I am not sure why your code is slow in the first place since you are already doing it asynchronously.

Comment: +1 `SDWebImage` is much more appropriate if you have a lot of images and also it allows bulk prefetching.

Answer (score 0):

AFNetworking is a fantastic framework and will make easy for you to do async image request.

However using AFNetworking **will not speed up** your code.

Probably will make your code slow, but the difference should be irrelevant, only if your images are too larger and the time to decode the image are high (I don't think this is the problem).

Comment: yeah, i think so. i need download many pictures like 2 or 4 MB of size... maybe that is the problem ...